# Wp Login redirect strips parameters from url

Tags: redirect, parameter, query-string

**If i write** `http://domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://domain.com/specificpage/?parameter1=dog&parameter2=dog&parameter3=cat` in the url address bar (to make the login page redirect to a specific page with parameters) and login.

**I get** redirected to the right page but only with first parameter (`http://domain.com/specificpage/?parameter1=dog`). the other two parameters are stripped from the url.

How can i solve that?

*Btw - the parameters are acceptable on this site (set in the functions file with `add_custom_query_vars` so that's not the problem).*

Comment: did you use some security plugin that limits URL length?

Comment: No. also if i type the url it self (the one that is set in the redirect_to) it's working fine without stripping the parameters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should encode the & to avoid potential conflicts:

```
http://domain.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http://domain.com/specificpage/?parameter1=dog&amp;parameter2=dog&amp;parameter3=cat
```

Comment: You should be using percent encoding, not HTML entities. See my answer.

Answer (score 1):

## Option 1: Using `wp_login_url($redirect)`:

[`wp_login_url`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_login_url/) takes an argument `$redirect` that will correctly generate the `redirect_to` query parameter correctly encoded:

```
echo '<a href="' . esc_attr( wp_login_url( "http://domain.com/specificpage/?parameter1=dog&parameter2=dog&parameter3=cat" ) ) . '">test</a>';
```

This would print:

```
<a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fspecificpage%2F%3Fparameter1%3Ddog%26parameter2%3Ddog%26parameter3%3Dcat">test</a>
```

As you can, special characters like `?` and `&` get encoded using [percent encoding](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) to `%3F` and `%26` respectively (not an HTML entity like `&amp;` as another answer suggested).

## Option 2: Using `http_build_query`:

If you didn't want to use `wp_login_url` but a more a general tool that applies to search queries in general, you can use PHP's [`http_build_query`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.http-build-query.php) instead, like this:

```
echo '<a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php?' . esc_attr( http_build_query(['redirect_to' => 'http://domain.com/specificpage/?parameter1=dog&parameter2=dog&parameter3=cat']) ) . '">test</a>';
```

This would print:

```
<a href="http://example.com/wp-login.php?redirect_to=http%3A%2F%2Fdomain.com%2Fspecificpage%2F%3Fparameter1%3Ddog%26parameter2%3Ddog%26parameter3%3Dcat">test</a>
```